# How to prove the convergence of an RL algorithm similar to Q-learning

Tags: discrete-mathematics, machine-learning

I am studying reinforcement learning algorithms. I learnt how to prove that the Q-learning algorithm is convergent from [[this paper]](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Emtjspaan/readingGroup/ProofQlearning.pdf). But I found a [[new paper]](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/wei20c/wei20c.pdf) where the authors propose a new RL algorithm. Their update formula is different from the traditional Q-learning algorithm. I'm confused about how to prove that their algorithm converges. Should I use the same methods as in the article about Q-learning? Please help me with this problem. Their update formula is as follows:
\begin{aligned}
Q_{t+1}\left(s_t, a_t\right) & \leftarrow\left(1-\alpha_\tau\right) Q_t\left(s_t, a_t\right) \\
& \qquad+\alpha_\tau  {\left[r\left(s_t, a_t\right)+\gamma \hat{V}_t\left(s_{t+1}\right)+b_\tau\right] } \\
\hat{Q}_{t+1}\left(s_t, a_t\right) & \leftarrow \min \left\{\hat{Q}_t\left(s_t, a_t\right), Q_{t+1}\left(s_t, a_t\right)\right\} \\
\hat{V}_{t+1}\left(s_t\right) & \leftarrow \max _{a \in \mathcal{A}} \hat{Q}_{t+1}\left(s_t, a\right) .
\end{aligned}

Comment: If it's possible to prove the convergence, then it's almost certainly with the same idea - you somehow need to satisfy Theorem $2$ of your first paper in this formulation. But if it does not seem to satisfy the conditions, then sometimes it is helpful to prove it in a simpler Bandit setting first.